# Can not get the confirmation message of ajax request to send sms?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, infobip-api

I have a code below. When I submit the form AJAX I got the SMS, but confirmation message not displaying on user front end. Also, how can I get the cURL response result. I use `var_dump($response)`, but it displays just `bool(true)` message sent or not sent. I follow some instruction in this PDF viewer [demo](http://dev.infobip.com/v1/page/downloads)

```
<?php   
 // send_sms.php     page

// Infobip's POST URL send sms
$applicantName = "test"; //name
$contactNo = "00"; // number

$postUrl = "http://api2.infobip.com/api/sendsms/xml"; 
$from = 'test';
$message = "Dear".$applicantName.",Thank you ...";  // message
$to = '21'.$contactNo;
// XML-formatted data
$xmlString =
"<SMS>
<authentification>
<username></username>
<password></password>
</authentification>
<message>
<sender>".$from."</sender>
<text>".$message."</text>
</message>
<recipients>
<gsm>".$to."</gsm>
</recipients>
</SMS>";
// previously formatted XML data becomes value of "XML" POST variable
$fields = "XML=" . urlencode($xmlString);
// in this example, POST request was made using PHP's CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
// response of the POST request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch); 
// end send sms process
if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {
echo "success";
}else{
echo "failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information about return values of a curl request..

Comment: how can i view the success or failed to a user (ajax)?

Comment: Well where is your code of that?

Comment: The code which is present here is of ajax one ??

Comment: i have a form which have 2 fields name and contact . which valided and submit by an ajax (url : 'send_sms.php'). above code. in success section i use $("#status").html(data);  .assume i have a div#status .

Comment: See You Got SMS. Right ? `var_dump($response)` displays `True` if sent. So put echo in `if($response)`.

Comment: What happened @RiyadhAhmed ? You Got Answer Or Not ?

Comment: sorry for late....@Nana Partykar..var_dump($response) display always true if message sent or not sent.Your can try just run the above mentioned code using wrong pass and username.

Comment: still need help ????